# Symlink for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, helpfile

Some people have suggested putting the symlink to the eclipse package at
/usr/local/bin while others suggest using /usr/bin

Is there any particular reason for including "local"?

See: http://grainier.net/how-to-install-eclipse-juno-in-ubuntu-13-04/
and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157452&p=12792387#post12792387

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/bin` is where the local user installed binaries are normally located.

> `/usr/local`: Tertiary hierarchy for local data, specific to this host. Typically has further subdirectories, e.g., bin/, lib/, share/.

while `/usr/bin` is for a more binaries with general propose:

> `/usr/bin`: Non-essential command binaries (not needed in single user mode); for all users.

If you like to know more about this, you can read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure).